# topScroll animation blocking the pages scroll in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I've built this website which is basically divided in 3 divs and i wrote a few animation scripts when scrolling through them.

```
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
```

I have the whole demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/7cv6zd1L/ where you can obviously see that after the animation to the 'portfolio' div my page won't continue to scroll downwards. I've had the same problem where it wouldn't scroll up but i fixed it here:

```
var lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function () {
                console.log(lastScroll);
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var divTop = $("#portfolio").offset().top;
                if ( scrollTop > lastScroll && scrollTop > $('body').height() / 3) {
                    $('body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: divTop
                    }, 50);
                }
                lastScroll = scrollTop;
            });
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic with the animation, a little help would be appreciated.

**P.S.** Don't let the missing images confuse you i didn't include them on purpose.

**EDIT:** I want to be able to use the same code from above in the transition to the next div.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @rafael To scroll freely through the web page with the scripts as well. if you opened the demo you would see that the scroll gets blocked at a certain point.

Comment: the IF with `$('body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: divTop
      }, 50);` is causing the problem because divTop is `#porfolio` offset. so the body is scrolling to that position. that's why you can't scroll down. what are you trying to achieve there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to be able to scroll down after the animation, then change this:

```
if ( scrollTop > lastScroll && scrollTop > $('body').height() / 3)
```

to this:

```
if ( scrollTop > lastScroll && scrollTop > $('body').height() / 3 && scrollTop < divTop)
```